# Is possible to have a different tag name in winui 3 user control?

Tags: user-controls, controls, winui-3

Is it possible to have a different tag name fo my user control?

My class looks like:

```
public sealed partial class ValidationControl : UserControl { ... }
```

and used like this:

```
<controls:ValidationControl Model="{x:Bind ViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="Name"/>
```

Is there some property in my user control that could change the tag name but that my class' name will continue naming **ValidationControl**?:

```
<controls:Validation Model="{x:Bind ViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="Name"/>
```

I have another class named Validation, that's why I cannot name only Validation to my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a one-liner marker type:

```
public class AlternativeName : ValidationControl { }
```

...and instantiate this one instead of the base class:

```
<controls:lternativeName ...
```

Don't forget to also remove the `sealed` keyword from the definition of the existing `ValidationControl` class:

```
public partial class ValidationControl : UserControl { ... }
```